# Fix problem with e.code not selecting the html class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select a div that has the class  eg. "keyA" which is the code the letter A is asigned.
I have a lot of divs like this and I need to access them but when I try to get them with queryselector, console says the value is null.
I thought since `.${e.code}` is the same string as the class, it would work.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="key keyA">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
    <div class="sound"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    const keyDown = document.querySelector(`.${e.code}`);
    console.log(keyDown);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Classes are case sensitive. `e.code` returns the String in the format of "Key{key}', and since your class name isn't capitalized, it isn't selected.

Change the class name so have a capital K (e.g, "`KeyA`").

```js
addEventListener("keydown",e=>{
    const keyDown = document.querySelector(`.${e.code}`);
    console.log(keyDown);
})
```

```html
<div class="key KeyA">
      <div class="letter">A</div>
      <div class="sound"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @wazz Have you run the snippet? It's working for me. You're supposed to click 'A'.

Comment: Ah, did not click 'A'. I do *not* know what's going on here. Trying to figure it out. : )

Comment: Huh, I knew about keyCode but never heard of plain `code` before. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event).